# Proving $a(n)$ is not prime for all $n\ge 8$

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Let $a(n)$ be the number formed by concatenating $n+1$ nines, $n$ zeroes and a one. I noticed the following pattern for the first 9 terms:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
n & a(n)& \text{Is prime} \\ \hline
0& 91 & \color{red}{\text{False}} \\ \hline
1& 9901 & \color{blue}{\text{True}} \\ \hline
2& 999001 & \color{red}{\text{False}} \\ \hline
3& 99990001 & \color{blue}{\text{True}} \\ \hline
4& 9999900001 & \color{red}{\text{False}} \\ \hline
5& 999999000001 & \color{blue}{\text{True}} \\ \hline
6& 99999990000001 & \color{red}{\text{False}} \\ \hline
7& 9999999900000001 & \color{blue}{\text{True}} \\ \hline
8& 999999999000000001 & \color{red}{\text{False}} \\ \hline
\end{array}

Interestingly, the pattern fails for $n>9$, and it seems that all the next terms are not prime (checked up to $n=1000$ with Python). So how would one prove that for $n\ge8$ all terms are not prime?

Comment: $a(n)=10^{2(n+1)}-10^{n+1}+1$ is divisible by $91$ if $n\equiv0$ or $4\pmod6$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner $a(8), a(9), a(11)$ and other terms are not prime and are not divisible by $91$.

Comment: The comment by @J.W. was meant to get you started, not to finish off the problem. But if you knew the factors of the ones that aren't prime, you might see some patterns and get some idea of what divisors all the larger examples might have.

Comment: Prime values for $ n = 2,4,6,8,$ with no others up to $n = 3400$ according to [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A168624)

Comment: May or may not be helpful to note that $10^{2n}-10^n+1=(10^{3n}+1)/(10^n+1)$.

Answer (score 2):

The smallest such number for which factordb does not know a prime factor is [here](http://www.factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000001406043112). According to my calculations with PFGW there is no further prime of the form $$(10^n-1)\cdot 10^n+1$$ up to $n=13\ 000$ , hence another prime of this form must have at least $26\ 000$ digits.

Small forced factors apparently do not exist and I think neither algebraic or aurifeuillean factors. In this case, there are probably infinitely many such primes, but already to find the next can be an enormous task.

Comment: just to clarify:  $100^{768}+1-10^{768}$ is composite, though we don't know a prime factor

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes , a number known to be composite without a known factor is screened with "C" in factordb.